Change tooltips of nodes in a highcharter sankey
This is a follow up of a older question (Change labels in highcharter sankey), where the solution shows how to change the tooltips in a R highcharter sankey for the links.
I now want to also change the tooltips for the nodes (Now it only says undefined). Ideally it should contain the sum of all the links per node.
This is a standard sankey:
    library(purrr) 
    library(tidyverse)
    library(highcharter)
    
    # data
    df <- tibble(from = c("Brazil", "Brazil", "Poland", "Spain", "Poland"),
                 toto = c("Portugal", "Spain", "Portugal", "Brazil", "Poland"),
                 exports = c(5324523.4523, 232452345.234, 2345234.52345, 3234523.45234, 63452345.2345),
                 head = "Exports")
    
    
    # standard sankey
    highchart() %>%
      hc_add_series(
        type = "sankey",
        data = df |> pmap(~ list(from = ..1, to = paste0(..2, ' '), weight = ..3, head = ..4))
      )

And with formatted tooltips (but only working for the links and not for the nodes):
# formatted tooltips (but tooltips for nodes dont work)
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "sankey",
    data = df |> pmap(~ list(from = ..1, to = paste0(..2, ' '), weight = ..3, head = ..4))
  ) |>
  hc_tooltip(formatter = JS("function () { return this.point.head + ': ' +'<b>' +
                             this.point.from + ' to ' +
                             this.point.to + '</b><br /> ' +
                             Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.weight)
                            }"
  )
  )

Screenshot:

I tried to follow https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/romtnqx5/ but I cannot make it work.
I am just able to change only the the tooltips for the nodes, but it works only when I just put text into it and without changing the tooltips for the links:
highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "sankey",
    data = df |> pmap(~ list(from = ..1, to = paste0(..2, ' '), weight = ..3, head = ..4, sum = ..5))
  ) |>
  hc_tooltip(
    nodeFormatter =  JS("function() {
    return 'only text works'
  }")
    # ,
    # formatter = JS("function () { return this.point.head + ': ' +'<b>' +
    #                          this.point.from + ' to ' +
    #                          this.point.to + '</b><br /> ' +
    #                          Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.weight)
    #                         }"
    # )
  )  

Thanks for any suggestions!

A series of type="sankey" allows to specify a tooltip formatter separately for the links (aka point) and the nodes using pointFormatter= and nodeFormatter= (see Different ToolTip text For Links and Nodes in Highcharts Sankey Charts):
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

# data
df <- tibble(
  from = c("Brazil", "Brazil", "Poland", "Spain", "Poland"),
  toto = c("Portugal", "Spain", "Portugal", "Brazil", "Poland"),
  exports = c(5324523.4523, 232452345.234, 2345234.52345, 3234523.45234, 63452345.2345),
  head = "Exports"
)


# standard sankey
highchart() |>
  hc_add_series(
    type = "sankey",
    data = df |> pmap(~ list(from = ..1, to = paste0(..2, " "), weight = ..3, head = ..4)),
    tooltip = list(
      nodeFormatter = JS(
        "function () {",
        "console.log(this);",
        "return this.name + ': ' +'<b>' +",
        "Highcharts.numberFormat(this.sum)",
        "}"
      ),
      pointFormatter = JS(
        "function () {",
        "return this.head + ': ' +'<b>' +",
        "this.from + ' to ' +",
        "this.to + '</b><br /> ' +",
        "Highcharts.numberFormat(this.weight)",
        "}"
      )
    )
  )


Thanks, just another thing, do you maybe know how to get rid of the "Series 1" at the start of the tooltips?

You can simply return an empty string within the headerFormat string templating inside the tooltip list: headerFormat = "". API: headerFormat

In addition to stefan answer, you can also utilize the nodeFormat & pointFormat string templating, which is recommended over using custom formatter callbacks.
 highchart() %>%
  hc_add_series(
    type = "sankey",
    data = df |> pmap(~ list(from = ..1, to = paste0(..2, ' '), weight = ..3, head = ..4))
  ) |>
  hc_tooltip(
    nodeFormat = "{point.name}: {point.sum}"
  )

API:
https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/templating
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.tooltip.nodeFormat
